# Ruby on rails internel error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

My English is very poor, please try to understand.

When i am running my sites in local host I get this error. I configure that site in SVN. My senior manoj also used my system that is not formatted please clear my error.

In browser:
                        Status: 500 Internal Server Error
                        Content-Type: text/html

```
              <html><body><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></body></html>
```

In log file:

```
                  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/_trace (30.8ms)
Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/_request_and_response (0.9ms)
Rendering /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/layout.erb (internal_server_error)
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon Feb 21 17:04:18 +0530 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined local variable or method `manojkumar' for #<Mongrel::CGIWrapper:0x7f5435366038>
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/cgi.rb:66:in `header'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:166:in `out'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in `handle_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch_without_newrelic'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch_without_newrelic'
    /home/kingston/workspace/CMS/vendor/plugins/newrelic_rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/dispatcher_instrumentation.rb:44:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client_without_proctitle'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client_without_proctitle'
    /home/kingston/workspace/CMS/vendor/plugins/mongrel_proctitle/lib/mongrel_proctitle.rb:119:in `process_client'
    /home/kingston/workspace/CMS/vendor/plugins/mongrel_proctitle/lib/mongrel_proctitle.rb:34:in `request'
    /home/kingston/workspace/CMS/vendor/plugins/mongrel_proctitle/lib/mongrel_proctitle.rb:117:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run_without_proctitle'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run_without_proctitle'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run_without_proctitle'
    /home/kingston/workspace/CMS/vendor/plugins/mongrel_proctitle/lib/mongrel_proctitle.rb:107:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
    /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Thanks,
kingston

Comment: When did you get this error? I mean doing what? on starting of the application or clicking on a specific link?

Comment: Reading your error, it looks like you have an undefined variable/method. What is 'manojkumar'?

Comment: when i am enter the url.

Comment: i donot know.but,my senior name.he was used my current system

Comment: When you enter what URL?

Comment: when i am start my server then i run my site with it's url in browser

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 0):

You have an undefined variable or method called `manojkumar`. Check `manojkumar` is spelt correctly and/or make sure it is a valid method.

Answer (score 0):

Would manojkumar be a user on your system that has a home directory you can't access?

My guess is that URL you are trying to access includes manojkumar.

Basically, CGIWrapper is looking for a directory or file called monojkumar and not finding it.